# SQL show the first line of a column if the identifier repeats without removing duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem displaying SQL results correctly,

I have an invoice to be paid partially, so each time I have a payment, then the invoice id is repeated several times and also the item name in the country, as in the photo below,

[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN7C9.png)

then I would like the display to look like this:

[result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzMs0.png)

Thanks for your help.

I hope I find a solution because this problem distorts the results in the reports

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And please show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: What you are asking for is something for your presentation layer, not your database layer. Each row has that information, so hiding it is a matter of display, not a matter of data. Of course you can do it in SQL... but its not the right place to do so.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can make use of `CASE` `ROW_NUMBER` in your `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) = 1 THEN column1 ELSE NULL END AS column1,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column2 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) = 1 THEN column2 ELSE NULL END AS column2,
    ...
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY columnN ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) = 1 THEN columnN ELSE NULL END AS columnN
FROM
    your_table;
```

Comment: This `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` is crazy, and does nothing, and should not be being taught to new SQL users.

Comment: And you only need to row_number once and then use it multiple times to hide values.